# GPUを用いた機械学習の環境構築で、CUDAやCUdnnなどは仮想環境でインストールするべき？

Tags: gpu

GPUを用いて機械学習を行おうと考えています。
そこで質問なのですが、CUDAやCUdnnなどは仮想環境でインストールするべきですか？
base環境でインストールしても問題ないのでしょうか。

Comment: 「仮想環境」には種類があります。何の仮想環境ですか？

Comment: 「base環境」と書いていることから推測するとAnacondaだと思われますが、「CUDA」とか「CUDnn」と書いた場合、その本体部分はPythonやAnacondaとは独立した別個のソフトウェア体系のもので、別個にインストールするものなのでは？ ただ、中には conda だけで構築できるという記事もあるようですので、主に使おうとするソフトウェアが何かによってどうインストールするのが効率的かは変わるかもしれませんね。[Windows でディープラーニング環境を整える](https://www.kkaneko.jp/tools/win/tfstack.html), [Ubuntu20.04にPythonとTensorFlowとCUDAとnvidia-driver(とcuDNN)...](https://qiita.com/python-nnn/items/805e7d09d55c96cb655c), [conda install のみでTensorFlowとGPU環境（CUDA、cuDNN）を構築する](https://qiita.com/ktokey/items/7ee9c112198a6b0b5709)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。